# Is there a way to restrict snippets to work under certain path

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a file structure like below

```
         main 
           |
      -------------
     |             |
  Folder1        Folder2
```

I have below JS snippets in my extension I want this to be available only on all the js files under Folder1 and similarly, I have some snippets that I want to be available only on the JS files under Folder2

```
"Print to console": {
    "scope": "javascript,typescript",
    "prefix": "log",
    "body": [
        "console.log('$1');",
        "$2"
    ],
}
```

don't want to do any manual changes to my vs code it should drive from the vs code extensions
I have gone through the documentation but still no luck, could someone please confirm if this is possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible but you could make this a command if you really wanted to...

Comment: maybe if you create a Multi Root Workspace on `Folder1` and `Folder2` and add a `.code-snippets` file in each `.vscode` folders